# How to add content description to Progress bar or Spinner in Android?

Tags: android, progress-bar, appium

How do we add content description or Accessibility id for the loading spinner or progress bar in Android for the purpose of test automation

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of test automation, certain elements need accessibility ids especially Selenium based automation. To add content description to the spinner or loader or progress bar or HUD in Android we add that in the **.xml file** of the progress bar. Developers may use different progress bars at different screens. So make sure you have added to the required progress bar or all progress bars, it's upto you.

```
<com.app_name.android.ui.widgets.XVProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:contentDescription="YOUR_ACCESSIBILITY_ID"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```